# Error while using onActivityResults() method

Tags: android

I am doing a test Paypal Application from this [link](http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/04/adding-paypal-payment-in-android.html). Following is part of my code,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResults(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println ( "Result Code : " + resultCode );
    switch(resultCode) 
    {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        System.out.println ( "Success" );
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
        System.out.println ( "Canceled" );
        break;
    case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
        System.out.println ( "Result Failure" );
    }
}
```

As long as I add `@Override` it starts showing me the following error:

> The method onActivityResults(int,int,Intent) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method

This is the image :

> [image]

If I remove `@Override` line, everything works fine but method `onActivityResults()` doesn't get called.

What should I do to remove this error?

Comment: @LaiVung, i didn't see any +1 ??

Comment: Sorry, but english is my third language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the wrong method, it's not `onActivityResults()`, but [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

Comment: Agree, how stupid typo mistake by me. Thanks buddy. will accept your answer soon :)